# Java on Windows on ARM (Snapdragon 835/850)?

Tags: java, windows, arm, qualcomm

Picked up an HP Envy X2 which has a Snapdragon 835 ARM processor (ARMv8). Is there an Oracle JDK or OpenJDK build available for Windows on ARM devices? Or is my best bet to use the x86 version (which would run under emulation)?

Comment: How was your experience in the end?